# Does HR asking for salary slips and earliest joining date mean I have got the job?

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer, job-change, india

I had 2 round of interviews and then after about a week, I got a mail from the HR saying "Kindly send me your last 3 months of salary slip and also let me know how soon you can join us.".

Does this mean I have got this job?

Comment: Ask them maybe? How can *we* answer that? I can speculate both ways and give reasons to say *no* and *yes*.

Comment: It's fairly standard, even early on, to check and verify the salary expectations of a candidate. It's even more standard to check when they may join the company as that's vital for planning purposes.

Comment: Without trying to sound facetious, the way you know you are being offered the job is when you receive official notification from a company offering you the job. While other signs may be positive, they are just that - signs.

Comment: so you got the job or not??

Answer (score 14):

Assuming this is an IT company in India (guessing from your name), it is almost certain you will get an offer from the company.

Your current salary is an important factor for companies to make hiring decisions, but they ask you for that information during the interview. They ask for salary slips for *verification* as part of their process, and they only do this for candidates whom they are interested in making an offer. Moreover, they ask for the earliest joining date so that the your prospective project manager can plan your training/assignments, should you accept the offer.

As the other answer and comments show, this works differently in other countries (US?) but in India, I am fairly certain it works the way I have described above.

**Edit**: Despite mentioning 'India' twice in the answer, some people still have a problem understanding that the "American Way" is not the only way people do business (see the comment below), so let me share some fun facts.<sup>1</sup>

1. I personally know a few people working in HR departments of reputed Indian companies (including the Indian subsidiaries of US-based MNCs), and I *know* from word of mouth that they follow the practice I have mentioned above.
2. Over the course of my rather short 7 year long career, I have been asked for salary slips and earliest joining date by 6 different companies, and I have ended up receiving an offer every single time. (That I did not accept any more than 2 of them is another matter.) Also, in cases where I have *not* been asked for salary slips, I have *not once* received an offer.

If this still doesn't satisfy you, then nothing in the universe will, no matter which planet you are from.

<sup>1</sup> You could argue till the cows come home whether the American Way is the "right" way or the "better" way, but that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @JimG.: The Indian work culture seems to be quite different from the Western one, in many ways, so I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @JimG How much of the planet have you seen? Hate to break it to you, but there are countries other than US on the planet. Just FYI, I personally know several people in the HR departments of various reputed IT companies in India, and I *know* that this is correct.

Comment: I dropped a mail to the company's HR asking about 'When i might expect to hear a decision about the next step from you?'  Then the HR replied "I am really very sorry for the delayed response. The final interview is still pending due to the technical manager was not available now i try to work on a new schedule with him than i will let you know'. What does this mean? After asking for payslips,they are scheduling another interview.

Comment: @ShashankVerma It means that I was wrong and you have been duped into sharing your salary slips for no reason. Companies need to know the salary paid in other companies doing similar business for their "internal benchmark". They typically get this info from certain agencies for a fee. This company got your salary info for free, by luring you into a job offer. You might still get the offer though. Although I doubt there is any law against this practice (because labour laws in India are quite retarded), but I would have probably put this company on my blacklist, and not go back to them again.

Comment: upvote for the edit part

Answer (score 13):

No. It means you are still in the group of people they think about and they need more information. It sure is a positive sign, but you only got the job after you both signed the contract, not one minute earlier.

Comment: It means you're a very strong contender, but it also means that you're probably tied with someone else on suitability and they're looking to take whoever's cheapest and can join soon. A positive and a negative, I guess.